Flask "TemplateNotFound" Error for index.html Despite Correct Folder Structure
I am building a web application using Flask for a school project. However, I’m encountering a recurring issue where Flask cannot find the index.html template. I’ve verified that the folder structure is correct, and the templates are in the appropriate folder.
Here’s my folder structure:
oshinosensei/
├── static/
│   ├── Lorem.jpg
│   ├── Ipsum.jpg
│   ├── ...
├── templates/
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── result.html
└── app.py

Despite the correct setup, Flask is unable to find the index.html template when I try to run the app. After running python app.py, the server starts successfully, but the page fails to load due to this error:
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html

I have confirmed that index.html is in the templates folder, and I’ve printed the current working directory in my app.py file:
import os
print("Current working directory:", os.getcwd())

The output confirms that the working directory is correct:
Current working directory: C:\Users\남경천\oshinosensei

import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)

I’ve also tried adding the template_folder='templates' argument when initializing Flask, but the error persists.
Any help or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!

You can try to recreate the template folder. And also it will be good just to try to set a simple Flask app like 'Hello world!'.This simple setup should help you verify that your Flask environment is correctly configured and that templates are being loaded properly. And something which I always do (but I am with PyCharm) to mark the directory as Template directory - I don't know if there is connection with the problem.
